# import data into QuickBooks Online using QuickBooks API and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks-online

Normally, data is imported to QuickBooks with Excel or csv file through the Import Data process.  We are looking for a way to import Customer, Vendor and Accounting data into QuickBooks Online using existing DLLs in QuickBooks API, with VB.NET.

So my questions are:
Do such DLLs that enable the import of this data exist in the QuickBooks API?  If so, where are they located?  And does any reference documentation for importing data with VB.NET exist?  Since I personally do not have access to QuickBooks (our client does), I would have to use the QuickBooks Sandbox for development, correct?  As you may have noticed, this QuickBooks API is new to me.

My searches for information about importing data into QuickBooks has generally returned information about the usual Import Data process with data in Excel spreadsheets.  I have looked through QuickBooks API and SDK documentation, but could not find VB.NET methods or programs for importing data.  Stack Overflow shows questions regarding Python, PHP, C# and Java for importing data, but I really need to see examples or at least instructions for programming the QuickBooks API with VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you asked for is documented on Intuit's website.

- .NET API - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_accounting/0010.net_tools#/716
- Sample code - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_accounting/0010.net_tools/0004_sample_code_and_sample_apps#/1409
- Class library documentation - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_accounting/0010.net_tools/0060_class_library_reference#/1416

And the highly recommended API overview:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000000_quickbooks_online_overview#/1371

To answer your specific questions:

> Do such DLLs that enable the import of this data exist in the QuickBooks API? If so, where are they located?

There is a .NET library, yes. Look at the links above, or Google for "quickbooks online .net api".

> And does any reference documentation for importing data with VB.NET exist?

Yes. Lots of it.

- Object reference: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting?isExpand=false
- Dev guides: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/accounting?isExpand=false#/1011

> I would have to use the QuickBooks Sandbox for development, correct?

Yes, a developer sandbox account is the correct place to do development.

> but could not find VB.NET methods or programs for importing data.

Lots of .NET sample code here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0011_sample_apps_and_code?isExpand=false#/1473

And here:

- https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/oauth-dotnet
- https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QuickbooksV3API-DotNet-Mvc3-Sample
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_accounting/0010.net_tools/0004_sample_code_and_sample_apps#/1409